# background-size doesnt work on section element the way it works on body element

Tags: html, css

as you guys know every HTML element has some properties by default.
when i try to style my body element with below code it will work.

```
body{
background-image: URL('imgaddress.jpg');
background-size: cover;
}
```

but when i try to style another element like section with the same style it doesnt work because it doesnt have any height same as body element, so here is my question.
which property of body element causes this? i mean which property make body element have a full screen background even tho there is no content in it and i didnt specify any height?

Comment: how you say there is no content in `body` you writing all the code between `body` tag  and body tag is the parent of all elements

Comment: Define `height`, `width` and `display:block` property

Comment: its not a real project dude im just practicing and in my test i didnt have any content in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which property of body element causes this? i mean which property make body element have a full screen background even tho there is no content in it and i didnt specify any height?

The `body` background is being [propagated](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds) in two steps — first onto the `html` element, which in turn passes it on to the canvas. The canvas, not targetable with CSS, always covers the entire page, which allows the background originally assigned to `body` to cover the entire page with `background-size: cover` even when there's nothing in the page. This behavior stops once you assign a different background to `html`, resulting in `body` being treated like any other block element such as `section` and `div`.

Note that this behavior isn't a default "property" of the `body` element in the CSS sense of the word — it's more of a special behavior standardized and baked into every browser, that's meant to reflect everyday intuition of a webpage's background covering the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

You can define height to fit-content/max-content

```
element{
    background-image: url('imgaddress.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height:fit-content;
}
```

Overall you need to use the height for other elements other than body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give min-height to your body element mentioned below,

```
body{
 background-image: URL('imgaddress.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
```

it is consider space without any content

Comment: tnx, i know how to style the section but thats not my question